# Saving a PDF file downloaded from browser

Tags: pdf, 3.2-honeycomb, firefox-for-android, adobe-reader

I have the need of downloading and forwarding a PDF receipt downloaded from Firefox (Firefox runs in Honeycomb, not on PC!). I know that the PDF should be "protected" because Adobe Reader on PC says so, however in Adobe Reader for Android I don't have any option more than "Info on Adobe Reader" to save or forward the file in an email.

My stock ROM comes with the shareware Docs To Go that wants me to buy the full version for saving/forwarding a file.

Am I missing something in Firefox to show some kind of open/save dialog instead of directly opening the file in a reader?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I found that all downloaded files are always stored in `/mnt/sdcard/Download` no matter they are "opened" or "saved" so I can grab them from there with any file manager